# Why isn't the 'Map Colors' fixup changing text colors?

Tags: pdf

Please see the screenshot beneath. I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC Version 2019.010.20064.

I'm trying to convert the book's default (C, M, Y, K) = (99%, 98%, 18%, 6%) (ie dark purple) to [(90, 0, 90, 0) (green)](https://www.colorhexa.com/1aff1a). After I click 'OK' and click 'Fix', Adobe Acrobat executes the fixup, but the color fails to change.

[image]

Comment: Just a guess: are you sure the PDF is CMYK and not RGB mode?

Comment: @jhurley Did you manage to download the PDF? 'Output Preview' exhibits CMYK percentages not RGB.

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal Please don 't ask people to download things. We're a bit weary of download links, because users never know for sure what they are downloading. If you are having specific problems, use (annotated) screenshots to illustrate them.

Comment: @PieBie If I remember, didn't someone ask me for the PDF so that he can download it? Was that comment deleted?

Comment: Yes. See my previous comment. We do not allow questions that depend on external files. Questions need to be self-contained, and potentially useful to others. If your problem cannot be solved without access to the original file, then it is a technical issue and not a design issue and it is out-of-scope for GDSE.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what went wrong at your end. I have used the exact same settings as you (see attached screenshot) and it worked as expected. What version of Acrobat are you using?
[image]

Comment: I have tried 2018.003.00009 Windows and 2019.010.20098 both without any issues. Can you import (via the options menu at the top right) this profile and try it [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mzuxs2m9hy6wtvn/Map_dark_blue_to_green.kfp?dl=0)?

Comment: The Profile that you have sent uses wrong input color (other than in your initial screenshot): C97 M55 Y28 K7 instead of C99 M98 Y18 K6. When I modify your profiles values it works as expected.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the delay; I forgot about this. Where do you see "C97 M55 Y28 K7"? As you can see, I input " C99 M98 Y18 K6" in my screenshot.